# struts 2 generated error/input page was not decorated by sitemesh

Tags: forms, validation, struts2, sitemesh

I was using sitemesh 2.4 with struts 2.3.14. Sitemesh correctly decorates the webpages except for one situation: when the form validation fails and struts 2 renders the original input jsp page with error messages. After researching online, I think the problem was that struts 2 simply renders the original input jsp page without calling another action to issuse an http request (for instance, redirect). Therefore sitemesh has no way to intervene to decorate the rendered jsp page.

So here is my question: Is it possible to instruct struts 2 to render the input jsp page AND fire an Http request so it can be intercepted by sitemesh?

Thank you in advance,

Relevant configurations in my web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I have this setup (no `<dispatcher>` entries) and it works as expected. Which Tomcat/Servlet version? Did your try replacing `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter` with the old `FilterDispatcher`?

Comment: @leonbloy,    Just realized I was on the wrong track. I changed my decorators.xml. Now sitemesh applies the theme to /* instead of /regular, where the input jsp page resides. appearantly struts2 put the renedered input jsp page to a different context/folder. That's why the rendered page was not decorated. Now it is correctly decorated. But the formatting on the error fields and messages are gone. :(

Comment: update...
<s:head /> was added to the jsp page to be decorated. After changing the pattern to /* in decorators.xml, <s:head /> wouldn't format the rendered jsp page any more. I tried to add <s:head /> into the theme page but always got jsp runtime exception. Finally I removed <s: head /> from both the theme page and jsp page. Added these two lines to the <head> of the theme page:

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/XXXX/struts/xhtml/styles.css" type="text/css"/>
<script src="/XXXX/struts/utils.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Now it's working. Still don't understand why can't use <s:head />.